# Calling findViewById() from an object

Tags: android

I'm practising an android app development and writing score board of billiards.

```
public class Board extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Rack rack;
    private int currentPlayer;

    public Board() {
        rack = new Rack();
        currentPlayer = 0;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayer(int n) {
        currentPlayer = n;
    }

    public void pocket(int ballNumber) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pocketed0);
        scoreView.setText("FOO");
    }
}
```

Having instantiated this board in MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Board board;

    String pocketedHistory = "";
    String pointString = "";
    int points = 0;
    String selectedPocket = "S";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        board = new Board();
    }


    public void pocket5(View v) {
        board.pocket(5);
    }
```

`pocket5()` is called when I tap a button and this exception was raised.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.android.japan9_ballscorer, PID: 10399
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18799)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18799) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:152)
> at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
> at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:389)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
> at com.example.android.japan9_ballscorer.Board.pocket(Board.java:21)
> at com.example.android.japan9_ballscorer.MainActivity.pocket5(MainActivity.java:27)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18799) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Could anyone shed a light about this? I'm at a loss what to do..

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Am so impatient that stopped a video of Udacity and started writing.

I thought it would be intuitive and straightforward for me to have Board object access views by findViewById(). That's why I stupidly had Board extend AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem here is usage and understanding of `Activities` and `Classes`. Your `Board` class doesn't need to be an Activity just to use the `findViewById` parameter. What you can do is pass the `context` of the `MainActivity` to the `Board` class as a `constructor` parameter.

Modify `Board` class as this:

```
public class Board {
    private Rack rack;
    private int currentPlayer;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public Board(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        rack = new Rack();
        currentPlayer = 0;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayer(int n) {
        currentPlayer = n;
    }

    public void pocket(int ballNumber) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) 
        mActivity.findViewById(R.id.pocketed0);
        scoreView.setText("FOO");
    }
}
```

And modify your `MainActivity` as such:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Board board;

    String pocketedHistory = "";
    String pointString = "";
    int points = 0;
    String selectedPocket = "S";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        board = new Board(this);
    }


    public void pocket5(View v) {
        board.pocket(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight, @Kidus ! When I changed the code, the medthod cannot be resolved as follows. Would you kindly shed some light?

>C:\Users\mitsu\AndroidStudioProjects\Japan9ballScorer\app\src\main\java\com\example\android\japan9_ballscorer\Board.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
>        TextView scoreView = (TextView) mContext.findViewById(R.id.pocketed0);
>                                                ^
 > symbol:   method findViewById(int)
 > location: variable mContext of type Context`

Comment: @uemurm did you not import the Context library/class in your Board class? `import android.content.Context;`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Kidus. Yes, `import android.content.Context;` is in that class file so `mContext` is resolved while `findViewById` is not.

Comment: @uemurm I edited my code check it out, switch `Context` with `Activity` since `findViewById` is required, I'm sorry I didn't check it thoroughly the first time.

Comment: Now I can proceed. Thank you so much, @Kidus !!

Answer (score 2):

you have:

```
public class Board extends AppCompatActivity 
...
```

but you don't have an `onCreate` or a `setContentView`, which is why your app is crashing. this leads me to believe that you don't have a complete understanding of what exactly *is* an activity

---

```
board = new Board();
```

you shouldn't be creating a new instance of an activity like this either, you have to launch an activity using an intent

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new in android the things are not correct you need to learn more.

For this problem you can try like this:-

```
    public class Board{
    private Rack rack;
    private int currentPlayer;

    public Board() {
        rack = new Rack();
        currentPlayer = 0;
    }

    public void setCurrentPlayer(int n) {
        currentPlayer = n;
    }

    public String pocket(int ballNumber) {
        return "FOO";
    }
}
```

Your Activity would be like this:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Board board;

    String pocketedHistory = "";
    String pointString = "";
    int points = 0;
    String selectedPocket = "S";
    TextView scoreView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scoreView = scoreView.findViewById(R.id.pocketed0);
        board = new Board();

    }

    public void pocket5(View v) {
        scoreView.setText(board.pocket(5));
    }
}
```